# getByName in POST HTTP request

Tags: android, http, url, post, android-asynctask

I'm trying to get the ip address of a host name then use it in the POST Http request URL  i'm sending to 
everything was working find and after adding the getByName line it suddenly crashed
So please help me and tell me exactly what could be the problem ? 
Thank you in advance

Logindb.java

```
    package com.example.loginad;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Logindb extends Activity {
Button login;
EditText u,p;
TextView res;
String result;
String x="mobile";
String host="";
Thread mBack;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.logindb);

        login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
        u=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.u);
        p=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.p);
        res=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.res);

        mBack = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {

        public void run()
        {
            try
              {
                     InetAddress address=null;
               address = InetAddress.getByName("Osama-PC");
                    host=address.getHostAddress();
              }
              catch(Exception e)
              {
                 e.printStackTrace();
              }         


        }
    }); 
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new MyAsyncTask().execute(u.getText().toString(),p.getText().toString());


            }
        });



    }
    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean>{

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            boolean success = postData(params[0],params[1]);        
            return success;
        } 

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean localres){

             if (localres){
                    res.setText("A Correct Username and Password");
                }else{
                    res.setText("Incorrect Username or Password");
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "command sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
            //pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }


        public Boolean postData(String a,String b) {
              ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
              postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", a));
              postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", b));
              postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobileid",x));
              // String valid = "1";
              String response = null;
              try {                 


                //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), host.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://"+host+"/new/check.php",postParameters);
//now in result you will have the response from php file either 0 or 1.                        
   result = response.toString();
                  // res = res.trim();
                  result = result.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                  // error.setText(res);

              } catch (Exception e) {
                  //res.setText(e.toString());
              }

           return "1".equals(result);





        }



    }





    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.logindb, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 130:

Change `return null;` to `return false;`

Or something smarter would be to change

```
if(result!=null)
{
    return result.equals("1");
}
else
{
    return null;
}
```

to

`return "1".equals(result);`

Comment: thanks i did edit it but now always give me Incorrect Username or Password 
Code Edited

Comment: Could you Log `result` so we can help you ?

Comment: I added a toast and it always displays that the value of Host is always empty

Comment: You must add the Host into the constructor of your `AsyncTask`. Then create a new class attribute to handle it. Think like if AsyncTask was in another file.